# Docker /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf not updating

Tags: apache, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that has the following command:

```
ADD 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

When I go into the interactive shell and open /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file I can see that it is not what I tried to upload.
Also I have watched the log in terminal while building and see the following entry:

```
Step 22 : ADD 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
 ---> b2a694916ad1
Removing intermediate container 175dd2c4f36e
```

Is there anything special I have to do to upload this file into my container?

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually uploading a different file?

Comment: @Tyler Hilbert it would make much more sense if you copy or add the file into the sites-available folder, and enable the config file after the successfull copy.

Comment: Did you solve this? Having the same problem.